# Program to generate sample log to feed to logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, log-analysis

I have written a small java program which generates some dummy logs (writes stuff to a txt file basically). Now I want to feed this data to the ELK stack. Basically logstash should read this data from the txt file and I want to visualize these changes on kibana, just to get a feel of it.

What I basically want to do is then change the speed at which my program writes the dummy logs to the txt file so that I can see the changes on kibana.

I have just started exploring the ELK stack and this might be a completely wrong way to do this kind of analysis. Please do suggest if there are other better ways to do this (considering I don't have actual logs to work with right now)

Edit : @Val

```
input {
    generator {
        message => “’83.149.9.216 - - [17/May/2015:10:05:03 +0000] "GET /presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/images/kibana-search.png HTTP/1.1" 200 203023 "http://semicomplete.com/presentations/logstash-monitorama-2013/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.77 Safari/537.36””
        count => 10
    }
}
```

So here is  my `logstash.conf`:

```
input {

 stdin { }

}


filter {
  grok {
    match => {
      "message" => '%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{USER:ident} %{USER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] "%{WORD:verb} %{DATA:request} HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion}" %{NUMBER:response:int} (?:-|%{NUMBER:bytes:int}) %{QS:referrer} %{QS:agent}'
    }
  }

  date {
    match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
    locale => en
  }

  geoip {
    source => "clientip"
  }

  useragent {
    source => "agent"
    target => "useragent"
  }
}

output {
  stdout {
codec => plain {
                        charset => "ISO-8859-1"
                }

}
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
    index => "apache_elk_example"
    template => "./apache_template.json"
    template_name => "apache_elk_example"
    template_overwrite => true
  }
}
```

Now after starting elasticsearch and kabana I do:

```
cat apache_logs | /usr/local/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f apache_logs
```

where `apache_logs` is been fed from my java program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("/Users/username/Desktop/user/apache_logs"));
        System.setOut(out);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.print("Exception");
    }
    while(true)
    //for(int i=0;i<5;++i)
    {
        System.out.println(generateRandomIPs() + //other log stuff);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

So here is the problem :

Kibana doesn't show me real time visualization i.e. as and when my java program feeds data into the `apache_log` file it does not show it to me. It only shows only until whatever data was already written into 'apache_log' at the time of execution of :

```
cat apache_logs | /usr/local/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f apache_logs
```

Comment: You can also use the [`generator` input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-generator.html) plugin.

Comment: you can use the file input. Have your program generate timestamps with a different name. Logstash will add its own timestamp in a field called @timestamp. The logstash timestamp will be the timestamp when it parses it, while yours will be the one of writing it. You do have to consider though that your java program also works asynchronously so there will be a delay

Comment: @Val can you illustrate how to use that plugin to generate "random" logs. Check edit.

Comment: You did it right, you can use the `lines` settings if you need to generate several different lines.

Comment: @Val So its basically one log many times or an array of logs repeated many times. If I want it to generate say 1000 logs each with different timestamp?

Comment: Ok, if you want 1000 different log lines, that's maybe not the right way, indeed. However, you can find tons of sample log files online.

Comment: @Val I don't want to use downloaded log files. I want to feed log stash data that it is been generated live so that I can view on kabana real time changes in plot .. and see the effect of varying the speed of log generation on kibana.

Comment: @pandaadb please check edit.

Comment: Sorry - I was too tired last night :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

might be a bit late but I wrote up a small sample of what I meant.

I modified your java program to add a timestamp like this:

```
public class LogWriter {


    public static Gson gson = new Gson();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("/var/logstash/input/test2.log"));
            System.setOut(out);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.print("Exception");
        }

        Map<String, String> timestamper = new HashMap<>();

        while(true)
        {

            String format = LocalDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);

            timestamper.put("myTimestamp", format);
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(timestamper));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This now write json like:

```
{"myTimestamp":"2016-06-10T10:42:16.299"}
{"myTimestamp":"2016-06-10T10:42:17.3"}
{"myTimestamp":"2016-06-10T10:42:18.301"}
```

I then setup logstash to read that file and parse it and output to stdout:

```
input {
  file {
     path => "/var/logstash/input/*.log"
     start_position => "beginning"
     ignore_older => 0
     sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }   
}

filter {
   json {
      source => "message"
   }
}

output {
    file {
           path => "/var/logstash/out.log"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

So it'll pick up my log, which knows when it was created, parses it, and creates a new timestamp which represents when it saw the log:

```
{
        "message" => "{\"myTimestamp\":\"2016-06-10T10:42:17.3\"}",
       "@version" => "1",
     "@timestamp" => "2016-06-10T09:42:17.687Z",
           "path" => "/var/logstash/input/test2.log",
           "host" => "pandaadb",
    "myTimestamp" => "2016-06-10T10:42:17.3"
}
{
        "message" => "{\"myTimestamp\":\"2016-06-10T10:42:18.301\"}",
       "@version" => "1",
     "@timestamp" => "2016-06-10T09:42:18.691Z",
           "path" => "/var/logstash/input/test2.log",
           "host" => "pandaadb",
    "myTimestamp" => "2016-06-10T10:42:18.301"
}
```

Here you can now see how long it takes for a log to be seen an processed. Which is around 300 miliseconds, which I would account to the fact that your java writer is an async writer and will not flush right away.

You can even make this a bit "cooler" by using the elapsed plugin which will calculate the difference between those timestamps for you.

I hope that helps for your testing :) Might not be the most advanced way of doing it, but it's easy to understand and pretty forward and fast.

Artur

Answer (score 0):

Changing input in log stash configuration file to

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/Users/purajain/Desktop/purak/logs/*"
    }
}
```

solved my problem.

[File](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html) plugin helps stream events from files.